# How to link or relocation unexported method of generics type in golang?

Tags: go

for example, I have file "pkg/A/internal/A.go" that has code like shown below

```golang
package internal

type AS[T any] struct {
}

func (s *AS[T]) helloLink() string {
    return "hello"
}
```

And I have another one file "pkg/B/B.go"

```golang
package B

import (
    _ "unsafe"

    _ "pkg/A/internel"
)

type BS[T any] struct {
}


//go:linkname pkgHello pkg/A/internel.(*AS[T]).helloLink
func pkgHello[T any](s *BS[T]) string
```

when I try to run this code, it tells that " parameterized function is missing function body"

1. I have set asm.s file in package B
2. It works without generics declaration
3. Ignore import path shown in code, it should be right

Comment: I _doubt_ that go:linkname supports this. Try asking on the golang-nuts mailing list.

Comment: @Volker Yep, I've asked in golang-nuts, sadly, it's not supported now. And to redesign compiler is too hard for me, but maybe try later